# button animation play constantly

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to play `fade` animation once after my button clicked and then go back to normal:

fade animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="100"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
/>
```

activity:

```
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View var1) {
                btn1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadein));
    }
        });
```

Now problem is that animation play constantly not once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`android:repeatCount="infinite"` to `android:repeatCount="1"`

Comment: omg i can't believe i didn't notice "repeatCount". Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

**use**

```
android:repeatCount="1"
```

**instead of**

```
android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

change in your   `Animation.Xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="100"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
/>
```